# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mpfr4/libmpfr4_3.1.3-1~14.04_amd64.deb Size mismatch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I'm newest on Linux platform. I'm use `Ubuntu-14.04` in Virtual machine. While running `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mpfr4/libmpfr4_3.1.3-1~14.04_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried a number of solutions each of which failed.how can to fix this?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Were any of those things that you ran the command to run given in the error message?  What happened when you ran it?

Answer (score 1):

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mpfr4/libmpfr4_3.1.3-1~14.04_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libmpfr4_3.1.3-1~14.04_amd64.deb
```

Comment: this works by skipping package verification (protection against man-in-the-middle), right?

Comment: yes., of course. you can verify it manually if you're paranoid.

Comment: Or one could fix the man in the middle.  (-:  I've had this happen with a particular HTTP proxy.